# Binding lightning:inputField to a client-side SObject instance not an SObject Id?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-inputfield, lightning-outputfield

My reading of the [lightning:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_inputField.htm) and related [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm) docs is that the record is read and written based on the Id supplied via the `recordId` attribute. There is no option to bind to a record that has already been loaded as [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) does via its `value` attribute. This makes `lightning:inputField` unusable in pure client-side logic where changes in one place are reflected in other places on the screen without round trips to the server.

So it appears that there is still no way to create input fields (or output fields) that are bound to the SObject metadata so saving a lot of tedious programming work (as `lightning:inputField` is) yet manipulate existing client-side data (as `lightning:input` does).

Or am I missing something here?

(For me leaving out the `recordId` as described in the help like this:

> To create a record create layout, use this component with
>   lightning:recordEditForm and pass in the object API name of the record
>   you're creating.

results in no fields being displayed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the value attribute is added now as a part of lightning:inputfield. To create a record here is a below code thats working for me

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome">

<aura:attribute name="companyName" type="String"/>
   <lightning:layout verticalAlign="start" multipleRows="true">
    <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
        <lightning:input type="text" label="Campaign" value="{!v.companyName}" aura:id="cmpName" onchange="{!c.handleOnchange}"/>
        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" 
                            objectApiName="Lead" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}" onload="{!c.handleOnload}">
            <lightning:messages />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Company" value="{!v.companyName}" aura:id="company"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Phone" />
            <lightning:button  variant="brand" class="btn" type="submit" label="Create new lead" />
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
   </lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

The Controller code for same

```
({
    handleSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
      console.log(event.getParams().response);
      for (let key of Object.keys(event.getParams().response)) {
        console.log(key + event.getParams().response[key]);
      }
     console.log(event.getParams().response.id);
},

handleOnchange : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("company").set("v.fieldName","Company");
    var company = component.get("v.companyName")
    component.find("company").set("v.value",company);
},

  handleOnload : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('Load Event' + JSON.stringify(event.getParams()));
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks Mohith, you are right that the `lightning:inputField` do render when there is no `recordId` and have an `onchange` attribute. Presently having trouble with the `value` attribute when the value is loaded after the `lightning:inputField` has been created: the value does not update. That's the problem Ravi is seeing too; having to programmatically set the value is a bit painful for me.

Comment: Agree its not two way binded and looks like it is manual at this point .

Answer (score 1):

[Spring 18 : Value Attribute in lightning:inputField](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207346/spring-18-value-attribute-in-lightninginputfield?noredirect=1#comment312920_207346)

Not sure if you are running into same issue. but i have a solution. please do check