# lightning:inputField "value" attribute not working as expected

Tags: lightning

**Below is my code**

```
<aura:attribute name="newModule" type="Module__c" default="{'sobjectType' : 'Module__c',
                                                                   'StartDate__c':'',
                                                                   'EndDate__c' : '',
                                                                   'Name' : ''}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ProgramId" type="Id" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:method name="ResetChild" action="{!c.handleReset}"/>



    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="NewModulePopUp" objectApiName="Module__c" onsubmit="{!c.createNewController}" 
                              onsuccess="{!c.showSuccess}" onerror="{!c.showError}">
    <lightning:messages />

        <lightning:inputField aura:id="namefield" fieldName="Name" value="{!v.newModule.Name}" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="ModuleType__c" value="{!v.newModule.ModuleType__c}"/>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="ModuleStatus__c" value="{!v.newModule.ModuleStatus__c}"/>

        <lightning:button label="Create Module"  variant="brand" type="submit" name="createmodule"/>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

**Below is my Controller**

```
 createNewController : function(component, event, helper){

            var action = component.get("c.createNewModule");
            console.log('MName' +component.get("v.newModule").Name); --> THIS IS BLANK
    }
```

why is object binding not working here? Is something wrong? Request to help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've hit the same problem - see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207330/binding-lightninginputfield-to-a-client-side-sobject-instance-not-an-sobject-id.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `lightning:recordEditForm` as you are trying to do.

First of all you have to enter `recordId` attribute in it, for editing a record, (without `recordId` for a new record), try reading the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm) for understanding how to write this.

Second - you do not need to set the value attribute for each `lightning:inputField` - the values will auto-populate after you add the recordId attribute to the lightning:recordEditForm component.

Third - in your controller, if you want to get a value or set a value from code, you should do like this:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper){
    // get value
    var nameValue = component.find("v.namefield").get("v.value");
    console.log(nameValue);
    // set value
    component.find("namefield").set("v.value", "new value to set");
}
```

Comment: I have a similar requirement but I want to set the field every time user clicks a button. With this code the button works fine as long as the user has not updated the field manually, else it doesn't works

Comment: please post a different question about that

Comment: Yeah I've posted - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238379/unable-to-update-record-edit-form-field-on-button-click