# Unable to update record edit form field on button click

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform

I have a requirement where I have a validate button for Lightning:recordEditForm on click of which it needs to update certain fields.
So my code is something like this

```
    <lightning:recordEditForm  aura:id="recordEditForm" 
                                    recordId="{!v.myObject.Id}"
                                    onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" 
                                    objectApiName="Address__c">
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Address_Line_1_Native__c" aura:id="addrNative" onchange="{!c.fieldValChange}" />     
<lightning:button variant="brand" name="Validate" label="Validate" onclick="{!c.validate}" />                       
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

and within validate() in JS

```
component.find("addrNative").set("v.value", "Accounting");
```

This works fine as long user is not entering anything in the field,but when user updates the field and clicks on validate, the button doesn't works

Found some similar question asked

1. [Not able to set value for Lightning:inputField field if it's manually modified from UI](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227840/not-able-to-set-value-for-lightninginputfield-field-if-its-manually-modified-f)
2. [Spring 18 : Value Attribute in lightning:inputField](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207346/spring-18-value-attribute-in-lightninginputfield/227674#227674)

The later has marked one answer as solution as well but that actually doesn't work

any suggestions?

Comment: your inputField is inside a loop of aura:Iteration. That mean there can be multiple inputFields with same aura:Id and when you try to set value it doesnt know to which input it should set value. Can you post the complete button click code we can figure out aw ay out.

Comment: My fault!Updated the code section. Please check again

Comment: please share the whole `validate()` method

Comment: code is this much only

Comment: I replicated the same bug in my org as well.. looks like an issue from sf side

Comment: any possible workaround?

Comment: try this workaround - take the lightning:button outside the lightning:recordEditForm. and for submitting the form use component.find("recordEditForm").submit().

Comment: have you tried setting v.value to null, then setting your value?